alias multiple columns
I have a table in sqlite and now I want to alias multiple columns, how can I do it?
For example, my columns are Name, Family, City and now I want to check a condition on them
SELECT (Name,Family,City) AS Personal From tblPersonal
WHERE Personal!=NULL


Why do you want an alias? Why not use AND?

You can't do it. This query is invalid on multiple levels. First, aliasing doesn't work that way at all. It's not a concatenation or tuple creation operator, it's only used to change the name of a single column. Second, the SELECT clause is evaluated after WHERE so aliasing isn't visible. Finally, you can't compare columns with NULL directly You have to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL. NULL isn't a value, it means the value is unknown. The result of any operation with an unknown value is unknown itself (ie NULL). In a WHERE clause that's translated as FALSE.

Besides, the condition  itself is unclear. Are you trying to check if all values are not null? Or if just one of them isn't null? Why not make the columns all NOT NULLABLE and prevent invalid values entirely?

What is the desired result you are excpecting from this query?

@kiner_shah Because there are too many columns in my table and I want to filter it by one condition

@winner_joiner I have many rows and columns and now I want to Select rows with value

@PanagiotisKanavos I know this query is invalid,,,I said is it possible to make query like this?,,,I have many rows and columns and it's hard to use AND or some activities like that

No you can't, in any SQL database. too many columns in my table that sounds like a design issue. Why not make the columns NOT NULLABLE from the start? What are the actual columns? Are you trying to create a wide instead of a long table, eg store values for 12 months as 12 columns instead of using rows with a Month columns? That's not a good design. Database tables aren't spreadsheets

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Updated answer:
Well if you want to check if all columns are NOT NULL the easy solution would be to concating/adding then, with the + operator:
SELECT Personal From 
    (SELECT  (Name + Family + City) AS Personal From tblPersonal) AS SubQueryPersonal
WHERE Personal IS NOT NULL

Since concating/adding NULL with the + operator results in NULL.
Just for completeness, if you want to use the columns you would have to add them, in both queries.
For example:
SELECT Personal, Name, Family, City From 
    (SELECT  (Name + Family + City) AS Personal, Name, Family, City From tblPersonal) AS SubQueryPersonal
WHERE Personal IS NOT NULL

Update 2:
I made a small online Fiddle, where this can be seen in action, and I also added the suggestion of using the || operator from @JonasMetzler comment, so that it can be compared.
But since this new field, is only used for checking if all columns are NOT NULL it should not matter, if you use + or ||.

While doing this, I found out, in SQLite it is possible to use Alias Names in the WHERE clause. It is non-SQL-Standard, but it works in SQLite, and like this you don't need a subquery. (Link to SO Post for details)
So this would be possible (in SQLite):
SELECT Name + Family + City AS Personal FROM tblPersonal WHERE Personal IS NOT NULL;

Old Answer is incorrect:
Even if I don't understand the why, theoretically you could build something similar (depending on your usecase you would need a different query)
But basically, you can create a subquery that use COALESCE (link to the documenation) achieve something similar:
SELECT Personal From 
    (SELECT COALESCE (Name,Family,City) AS Personal From tblPersonal) AS SubQueryPersonal
WHERE Personal IS NOT NULL


Just to explain: COALESCE returns the first non-Null Argument, so it should have the desired effect.



+ is addition, not concatenation...

@Shawn thanks for your feedback, I would have also called + is the addition operation, but I opted to use the same naming as in this SQL documentation. And yes this is for the SQL Server not Sqlite, but this operation seems to work the same also on Sqlite.
